# Can you have a timed trigger for a google drive table?

Tags: google-drive-api

Can you have a timed trigger for a google drive table?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) of Google Apps Script which allows scripts to create, find, and modify files and folders in Google Drive. Then check the [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to let scripts execute at a particular time or on a recurring interval, as frequently as every minute or as infrequently as once per month.

> Note that an [add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons) can use a time-driven trigger [once per hour at most](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#limitations). The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m., then keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours elapse before the trigger fires again.